# I need Reference and Explanation of all C standard functions

Tags: c

I was programming in C ,... but some months ago I start learning .Net 
the C programming lang is not easy , 
That's why I need reference of all reference and explanation of all C standard function

Comment: I'm confused as to why there's .NET written somewhere in this question.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=c+standard+library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only *authoritative* place to look this stuff up is in the C standard.

The final versions of the standards cost money, but here's a copy of a post-standardisation modification of ISO C99 (that is, ISO/IEC 9899:1999), incorporating corrections published in 2001 and 2004:

http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

If you want the C89 standard, then you may have to buy it, although you can get pre-standardisation drafts online that barely differ from the standard.

Do not look it up on cplusplus.com, which primarily defines the C++ versions of the functions, which are not what you want. Firstly they sometimes differ from any version of C (for example, `strchr`), and secondly C99 has introduced keyword restrict into a lot of standard function signatures.

Do not look it up on Wikipedia (which is incomplete). Do not even look it up in the GNU libc documentation (which in any case summarises the function descriptions), since that documents behaviour guaranteed by glibc (which you aren't even using), but not guaranteed by the standard (so other implementations will differ).

Actually, I confess, I often look this stuff up on opengroup.org. But that's because I'm (a) lazy, and (b) often working with POSIX systems, so the POSIX incorporation of the C standard is relevant. I would not recommend it as a reference to a beginner with C on a non-POSIX system.

However, since you're working on a Microsoft system, looking it up on MSDN would likewise be valid, provided you are not trying to write portable code. In fact, popular C compilers (including MS and GCC) currently implement something in between C89 and C99, so in practice you can't write "standard C99". You must instead consult your compiler's documentation in addition to the standard.

Answer (score 4):

[Okay, here you go.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C_functions)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/index.html

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of a multitude of possible references: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library